# Integral with log and powers

Tags: integration

What is $$\int_{0}^{1-k} \log \Big({1-t \over t} \Big) t^{(1-q)n-1}(1-t)^{(q-r)n} dt$$

I know that $q>0.5$ and $r<q$. $n$ is a positive integer.

Comment: What have you tried?  What happens if you integrate by parts?  Do you know anything about $q$, $n$, and $r$?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I have added the assumptions!

Comment: @MichaelBurr I have tried integration by parts but it made it more complicated

Comment: What you essentially have is the subtraction of two derivatives of the incomplete beta function.